# ios 14 keyboard height

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, ios14

I am getting keyboard height with keyboardwillshow notification so that i move the view up when keyboard appears. It was working fine before ios 14. However on ios 14 when user clicks textfield the app suddenly crashing because of not receivng keyboardwillshow notification and hence keyboard height is nil.
How can i get the keyboard height in ios 14 so that i can move view up?
Below is my code that working fine for ios version 13:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)

var keyboardHeight : CGFloat!

@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            keyboardHeight = keyboardSize.height-view.safeAreaInsets.bottom
        } else {
            keyboardHeight = keyboardSize.height
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
        
        print("keyboard height is \(keyboardHeight)")
    }
}
```

Comment: This might help you: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html

Comment: i am already using this. but on ios 14 keyboarwillshow notification not working anymore